# How to take the back up of contacts on PC from 8X, do we need Zune to connect with PC?

Tags: contacts, windows-8

I find it very difficult to take the back up of contacts on my Windows 8 PC, I think I might need Zune to connect with PC, but Call Center person told me to just connect the device with PC, and I will get a POP UP to sync the contacts, but I tried it at least 10 times but no go.

Comment: WP8 devices don't use Zune at all. Do your contacts Sync with an existing service like Outlook.com, Gmail.com, etc?

Comment: @NeilTurner I have already backed up on my Live ID, but may I take the back up on my PC as .vcf file?

Comment: It's probably easier to log into your Outlook account and export all your contacts from there.

Answer (score 1):

No, **it's not possible** to synchronize contacts between your PC and phone **via USB**.

To synchronize your contacts from you phone to your PC and vice versa you need to use a **cloud service** like [Outlook.com](http://www.outlook.com).

You can find instructions for how to do it [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/people/sync-contacts-and-calendars-from-outlook-on-my-pc-to-my-phone).

Answer (score 0):

If you have outlook you can sync them with outlook using the following set of instructions:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/people/sync-contacts-and-calendars-from-outlook-on-my-pc-to-my-phone

Answer (score 0):

As You have already backed up your contacts on your Live ID. It is much easier to export them from outlook.com on your PC.

Just follow the steps.

1. Login to outlook.com with your Microsoft account that has your contacts.
2. Click on the menu (top-left) and click People.
3. Now you see your contacts, and right below menu you see All checkbox. Click it to select all your contacts.
4. Once selected click on 'Manage' on the top bar and select 'Export for outlook.com and other services'. Then that should download all your contacts in .csv format.

Hope this helps.